# Best way to represent matrix of ratings in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix

I am trying to build a recommender system in c#.
I am wondering what would be the best way to represent a matrix of ratings.
Every row will represent user and every column will represent a movie.
For example the cell in the 2nd row and 4th column will represent the rating (1 to 5 stars, for instance) of the 2nd user to the 4th movie.

It is worth saying that I will need to make some matrix algebra with the data such as multiplication transpose etc.
Also the matrix will be sparse, because not all users rated all movies, of course.

The obvious way to do so is an array of strings of usernames, a strings array of movies, and an integers 2d array of ratings:

```
string[] users = new string[5] { "David", "Matt", "Ben", "Chris", "Torri" };
string[] movies = new string[4] { "Titanic", "X-men", "Snatch", "Speed"};
ratings = new int[5, 4];
```

The question is what would be the best data structure to use? 
Thanks all!

Comment: I fail to see where you'd need linear algebra for such a system.  Seems like collections of users and movies would be enough - average all ratings for each movie, etc.  If a user didn't rate a movie would you give it a 0?

Comment: If you're going to be doing matrix arithmetic, it might be worth investigating the [`.Net Numerics (Math.Net) libraries`](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/Matrix.html) but like D Stanley said, why would you be doing matrix arithmetic on it?

Comment: Recommender system needs a lot of algebra.
I will have to calculate correlation, collaborative filteringand much more...

Comment: No....it shouldn't if you keep it simple...

Comment: You might want to consider how you are going to store it in your database first... that might influence how you use it in your application.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is asking. Are you wondering what variable type you should use to hold the matrix or how to display it?

Comment: The question is what would be the best data structure to use?

Comment: I suggest you add that to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Best way* is using an object-oriented programming approach:

```
// Note I'm going to use HashSet<T> everywhere because both movies and
// users should be unique in their respective collections

public class User 
{
    public sealed class UserEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<User>
    {
          public bool Equals(User a, User b)
          {
              return a != null && b != null && a.Name == b.Name;
          }

          public int GetHashCode(User some)
          {
              return some.Name.GetHashCode();
          }
    }


     public string Name { get; set; }

     // C# 6 expression bodied properties!!!!
     public HashSet<Movie> LikesMovies { get; set; } = new HashSet<Movie>(new Movie.MovieEqualityComparer());
}

public class Movie
{   
    public sealed class MovieEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Movie>
    {
          public bool Equals(Movie a, Movie b)
          {
              return a != null && b != null && a.Name == b.Name;
          }

          public int GetHashCode(Movie some)
          {
              return some.Name.GetHashCode();
          }
    }

     public string Name { get; set; }

     // C# 6 expression bodied properties!!!!
     public HashSet<User> UsersWhoLikeIt { get; set; } = new HashSet<User>(new User.UserEqualityComparer());
}
```

Now if you want to represent that someone called *John* likes *Star Trek* you would do this:

```
HashSet<Movie> movies = new HashSet<Movie>(new Movie.MovieEqualityComparer())
{
    new Movie { Name = "Star Trek" },
    new Movie { Name = "Star Wars" }
};

HashSet<User> users = new HashSet<User>(new User.UserEqualityComparer())
{
    new User { Name = "John" },
    new User { Name = "Jack" }
};

// Now an user likes a movie:
Movie movie = movies.Single(some => some.Name == "Star Trek");
User user = users.Single(some => some.Name == "John");

// You need to associate both sides of the whole M-N association:
// A movie can be liked by many users and an user can like many movies...
movie.UsersWhoLikeIt.Add(user);
user.LikesMovies.Add(movie);
```

Once you've filled your object graph with objects, you only need to work with LINQ and its numerous extension methods and own `HashSet<T>` interesting methods like intersections.

Using OOP has a big advantage: you can use an OR/M to map this domain to a relational database and store your data, or you can practically store it in NoSQL databases directly.

Note that I've provided you a sample of implementing *likes*. Ratings would be represented by other entity *MovieRating* where you can add as properties as needed to represent your rating system.

Comment: it looks like you defined public class Movie twice.

Comment: Why not just have the class implement GetHashCode and Equals?

Comment: @Frisbee You can do both things, but the `IEqualityComparer<T>` approach has an advantage: you can provide different equality comparers to a `HashSet<T>` to define *what's an equal object* depending on the domain or in other cases....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain a matrix is the best approach, but I'm also making the assumption here that you are just storing ratings.

I'm not sure about a *best way*, but a *better way* to represent user movie ratings would be to model the users, movies, and ratings separately.  Later you can choose to serialize the values to a file, or interface with a database, or whatever other solution you can find for data persistence.

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Movie
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class Rating
{
    public User RatingUser { get; set; }
    public Movie RatingMovie { get; set; }
}
```

Next, dynamically add the User, Movie, and Rating models into simple collections like a list.  You can query these collections using LINQ.  Also, the models will scale much more nicely (e.g. refactoring name into first and last name for User, or adding a rating to Title).  Here is an example of using the lists, and adding user and movie values from the code you provided.

```
public List<User> UserList = new List<User>();
public List<Movie> MovieList = new List<Movie>();
public List<Ratings> RatingList = new List<Rating>();

UserList.Add(new User() { Name = "David"} );
UserList.Add(new User() { Name = "Matt"} );
UserList.Add(new User() { Name = "Ben"} );
UserList.Add(new User() { Name = "Chris"} );
UserList.Add(new User() { Name = "Torri"} );

MovieList.Add(new User() { Title = "Titanic"} );
MovieList.Add(new User() { Title = "X-men"} );
MovieList.Add(new User() { Title = "Snatch"} );
MovieList.Add(new User() { Title = "Speed"} );
```

Comment: I think you meant :
public List<Ratings> RatingList = new List<Ratings>();
public List<Movie> MovieList = new List<Movie>();

Comment: Indeed, I did.  fixed!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do matrix algebra then like you have it but you don't need an int for 1-5 rating

```
ratings = new byte[5, 4];
```

Use 0 for not rated or byte? and use null for not rated

You cannot (easily) resize an array
So save user, movies, and user rating in the database in a non-matrix way
You would then size the array and load from the database

```
ratingtable:    
int userID  PK   
int movieID  PK   
byte rating
```

in the table you don't store null or 0 for rating
if it is not there then it is not rated